# padding inside the main container between navbar and footer

Tags: html, css

Hey guys as the title says, I have a navbar and a footer, for now I haven't sticked the footer to the bottom. but the code I have nothing such vulnerable and thats why im unable to find whats causing the problem. now onto the problem, between the header and footer the content should start from the beginning meaning 0 padding and 0 margin but instead it somehow adds padding-left
-- picture of problem
[image]

my main file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/onio.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themify-icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/onio.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/onio_split.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="overflow: none;">
        <?php include 'core/main.php'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

my html

```
<nav class="onio_nav">
    <ul class="onio_item_left">
        <li class="onio-item">
            <div class="bars_container">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="onio_item_right">
        <li class="onio-item px">
            <div class="private_container px">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope" class="envelope"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="onio-item px">
            <div class="private_container px">
                <i class="fa fa-globe" style="padding-left: 9px;"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="onio-item px">
            <div class="private_container px">
                <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="onio-item px">
            <div class="logo_container">
                <img src="default_images/default_avatar.png" />
            </div>  
        </li>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Profile
                </li>
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Profile
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ul>   
</nav>
sdsd
<nav class="onio_nav">

</nav>
```

my css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}
.onio-item {
    padding-top: 7px;
}
.onio_item_left {
    padding-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.onio_item_right {
    float: right;
    padding-top:1px;
}
.px {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.onio_item_right li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.bars_container {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #7f8c8d;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 0.9s;
}
.bars_container i {
    padding-left: 9.3px;
    padding-top: 7.8px;
    font-size: 19px;
}
.private_container {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #7f8c8d;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 0.9s;
}
.private_container i {
    padding-left: 8.5px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.bars_container:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(200deg, rgba(58,180,177,1) 21%, rgba(29,253,217,1) 79%);
    color: white;
}
.private_container:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(200deg, rgba(58,180,177,1) 21%, rgba(29,253,217,1) 79%);
    color: white;
}
.logo_container img {
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.dropdown {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: none;

}
.dropdown li {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    color:  white;
    z-index: 999;
}
.dropdown li:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #2c3e50, 0 0 40px #2c3e50, 0 0 80px #2c3e50;
}
```

Comment: please share a  snapshot of the problem

Comment: Please share an image of the problem

Comment: @midnightgamer done

Comment: Run your code, no problem found. I have encountered similar problems in your picture. The height of the left menu icon exceeds the height of the container, That includes the value 'margin-bottom'. The text has no spacing, but the icon is too high to hold the text close to the left.

Answer (score 0):

The `<ul>` tag also has `padding-inline-start` as a css value for all its `<li>` children. If you want to remove this, you should go:

```css
ul {
    padding-inline-start: 0;
}
```

Or you can use classes if you only want some `<ul>` elements to not have the padding.

Comment: But will it solve the padding problem between the navbar and footer?

Answer (score 0):

As your code is having ul and li then by default ul tag has some padding in it which is very easy to remove you just to need to select that ul either by `ul tag` or by `adding a class` to it and then in css mention it as `0px`

I have attached a JS Fiddle for example:-
https://jsfiddle.net/anft8huo/

In this example you can remove the padding in css to see how does it affect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I did add the padding 0 to my ul selector. But the question is why is the padding being applied to the text between the navbar and footer

Comment: The problem is that by default, browsers have custom css - in chrome for example:-

`ul, menu, dir {
   display: block;
   list-style-type: disc;
   -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
   -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
   -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
   -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
   -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be just adding the main tag and set padding margin to 0.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
}
.onio-item {
    padding-top: 7px;
}
.onio_item_left {
    padding-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.onio_item_right {
    float: right;
    padding-top:1px;
}
.px {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.onio_item_right li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.bars_container {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #7f8c8d;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 0.9s;
}
.bars_container i {
    padding-left: 9.3px;
    padding-top: 7.8px;
    font-size: 19px;
}
.private_container {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #34495e;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #7f8c8d;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 0.9s;
}
.private_container i {
    padding-left: 8.5px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.bars_container:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(200deg, rgba(58,180,177,1) 21%, rgba(29,253,217,1) 79%);
    color: white;
}
.private_container:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(200deg, rgba(58,180,177,1) 21%, rgba(29,253,217,1) 79%);
    color: white;
}
.logo_container img {
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.dropdown {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: none;

}
.dropdown li {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    color:  white;
    z-index: 999;
}
.dropdown li:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #2c3e50, 0 0 40px #2c3e50, 0 0 80px #2c3e50;
}

main{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="onio_nav">
    <ul class="onio_item_left">
        <li class="onio-item">
            <div class="bars_container">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="onio_item_right">
        <li class="onio-item px">
            <div class="private_container px">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope" class="envelope"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="onio-item px">
            <div class="private_container px">
                <i class="fa fa-globe" style="padding-left: 9px;"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="onio-item px">
            <div class="private_container px">
                <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="onio-item px">
            <div class="logo_container">
                <img src="default_images/default_avatar.png" />
            </div>  
        </li>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Profile
                </li>
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Profile
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ul>   
</nav>
<main>
  sdsd
</main>
<nav class="onio_nav">

</nav>
```

Comment: bootstrap added some extra css for styling purpose If you have to overwrite use !important.

Comment: I tried adding the !important to the body as well as the main tag but it dosen't seem to fix the problem

Comment: It is but its not working when Im removing the bootstrap. I don't want to get rid of bootstrap as it will change everything on my navbar

Comment: share you whole codebase , bootstrap might be causing the problem

Comment: I have the headers attached to this file from another file, and the header only contains the bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

Only in this case will the situation you describe appear. Even if the height is more than 1px, it will block the text to the left.
[image]